# Can you have more than one HTTP Message Handler for HttpClient?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

I need to query against a Web API that sends responses which can be encrypted and/or compressed and/or Base64 encoded and I'd like to implement this as a chain of `HttpMessageHandler`s very much like outlined in [this post](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers), which is for Web API though.

There is a constructor for `HttpClient` taking an `HttpMessageHandler`, so that is a start. Do I have to come up with a solution for chaining multiple handlers myself or is there maybe a better option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to chain `HttpMessageHandler`s is to inherit from [`DelegatingHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler.aspx), which takes an inner `HttpMessageHandler` in its constructor, which it calls in its base `SendAsync` implementation.

```
public class MyHandler1 : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // do something before the inner handler runs (modify the request?)

        var response =  await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        // do something after the inner handler runs (modify the repsonse?)

        return response;
    }
}
```

Armed with multiple of these, you chain them together in whatever order you want when you construct `HttpClient`:

```
var client = new HttpClient(
    new MyHandler1(
        new MyHandler2(
            new MyHandler3(...))));
```